# mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia with "window" for displaySurface, streams the whole browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screensharing

I'm using `mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` with config

```
 { audio : false, video : { displaySurface : "window" }}
```

The Chrome popup appears then I select the tab I want to share but the stream is the entire browser, the `displaySurface` value seems ignored and fallbacks onto "browser".

I'm using Chrome 112 and I was wondering if this is a known bug, or this is the expected behavior?

Edit: I'm getting the same result from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) (scroll down to Result to test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution so I answer my own question, hoping it helps someone.
The key is to set `preferCurrentTab` and `browser` instead of `window`

```
 { preferCurrentTab: true, audio : false, video : { displaySurface : "browser" }}
```

in the options for `getMediaDisplay` and then the tab is already selected and the stream is the window.